# Button is visiable but TextView / ImageView is not visiable in custom compound view

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-widgets, android-compound-view

I am trying to create compound CardView using two CardView and extended Framelayout. If I place a button inside custom CardView as a child the button is visible but if i place TextView or ImageView as a child the widget (TextView or ImageView) is not visible.

Screenshot of Custom widget with TextView as child

[image]

Screenshot of Custom Widget with Button as child

[image]

kotlin code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView


class CompoundCardView : FrameLayout{

    private var childView:CardView? = null

    private var heading:String? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
            requestLayout()
        }
        get() {
        return field
        }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context, null)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }


    constructor(context: Context,
                attrs: AttributeSet,
                defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }
    private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.CompoundCardView,0,0).apply {
            try {
                heading = getString(R.styleable.CompoundCardView_heading)

            }finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }

        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.compaund_card_view,this,true)
        childView = findViewById(R.id.holder)
        val header:TextView = findViewById(R.id.header)
        header.text = heading
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?) {
        invalidate()
        childView?.addView(child,0, child?.layoutParams)
        requestLayout()
    }
}
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:strokeColor="#2196F3"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFC107"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:contentPaddingBottom="4dp"
        app:contentPaddingLeft="8dp"
        app:contentPaddingRight="8dp"
        app:contentPaddingTop="4dp"
        app:strokeColor="#2196F3"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/heading"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</merge>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting different text color for TextView? It looks like you have white text on white background

Comment: @SergeiKozelko I have tried different text color . But it does not work. The image view also showing its position but not its content.